# Using the postman I try to test, various scenarios for my APIs. But I have a question, if I have an authentication API, how can I reuse a token?

Tags: java, api, testing, automation, postman

But I have a question, if I have an authentication API (I don't use any authorization method), it generates a different token for me every time in response (after a POST request), to be used in other APIs, how can I add that token in the environment to be taken automatically and only called in the other APIs?

For example, to be a little more specific:
POST Request

```
{
"username": "test",
"password": "password"
}
```

Response:

```
{
"status": 0,
"message": "success"
"token":"zxvnm5yrhd6dfdfd6fd8g56f6teui5AXgGk851"
}
```

That token needs to be added to other APIs in order to be tested, but I want it to be added automatically, or just to call it, so I don't always have to copy-paste.

And another curiosity, can you give me some recommendations for tutorials, on how to automate the tests in postman, and the alerts/tests to get your results by email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After successful register, you can set your token variable as an environment variable.
For instance, set your variable as {{autToken}}
set your value with `pm.environment.set("autToken", userData.accessToken);`
After that, at every other API using that token in your postman tests, set authorization parameters as Bearer token (if your token is bearer token) and give that env variable as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and somehow you have a suggestion for this question as well: can you give me some recommendations for tutorials, on how to automate the tests in postman, and the alerts/tests to get your results by email?

Comment: You are welcome, I highly recommend Valentin Despa's tutorials, the all information about Postman I learned with his free tutorials on youtube. Also, Postman has great documentation. In addition, you can follow the postman community. You can automate your tests running with Monitors functionality with the postman and send the results with set schedules. 
You can review the documentation here https://learning.postman.com/docs/monitoring-your-api/setting-up-monitor/

Comment: Also, there is a CLI tool Newman to automate your tests run, you can run your tests with command and integrate this command in Jenkins with a pipeline.
Also, Newman documentation is here
https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable for your collection, which will hold the token, lets call it `access.token`. [How](https://community.postman.com/t/how-do-i-set-a-collection-variable/5466) to do it.

You can add a test after request for getting access token, which actually won't test anything, but will set the variable value.

```
pm.test("Set access token", function() {
    console.log("Attempting to set access token variable");
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
    let token = pm.response.json()["token"];
    if (token === undefined || token === "") {
        console.log("Missing access token");
        return;
    }
    pm.collectionVariables.set("access.token", token);
});
```

This example actually tests for response status code to be 200, but you can remove/change it depending on needs. The first step is not really needed, setting the variable in the test will create if it is missing.

Then you can use the variable in your other requests like this:

```
{{access.token}}
```

Check the [postman guide](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#using-variables) as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and somehow you have a suggestion for this question as well: can you give me some recommendations for tutorials, on how to automate the tests in postman, and the alerts/tests to get your results by email?

Comment: @UtiAnm I suppose you could [integrate](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/integration-with-travis/) with Travis CI and have travis send emails, but that's just a **guess**.  I don't know of a way to do it directly with postman. It would be better to ask a different question about it(with prior research of course).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and information, in the future I will ask the questions separately

Comment: Do you have any idea why, if I write the code below, the value of the token is null on the environment?

Comment: @UtiAnm Not sure i understand your question, but the code above sets `collection variable`, not `environment variable`.

Comment: the token variable is created, but the value is null in the environment. Also, I run the authentification API, the token code is displayed in the response. I try to find a way that code is retained in the environment token variable.